# Can anyone remove a clone's inhibitor chip?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

**spoilers for TCW season 7**

In season 7 of TCW, Ahsoka is able to remove the inhibitor chip from Rex using the medical chamber.  Is this something that anyone could do?  I heard a rumor that only someone who's Force-sensitive can remove a clone's chip, but I don't think that's been explicitly confirmed in the show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Canon tab for Wookieepedia for the [Behavioral modification biochip](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Behavioral_modification_biochip) notes that:

> [The biochips] were microscopic in size, and this combined with their biological nature made them extremely difficult to detect with standard medical equipment: it took a Level 5 atomic brain scan to find the chip inside the head of trooper Tup, after lower-level scans failed to register any anomaly. ("[Clone Wars: Conspiracy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Conspiracy)") Ahsoka Tano was later unable to detect a chip with the standard medical facilities onboard a *Venator*-class Star Destroyer until she used the Force to locate it. ("[Clone Wars: Shattered](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shattered)")

So, yes, it does sound like it requires sophisticated equipment or Force powers to be able to detect it, which would be required for removal.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  That does make sense, and that will make it interesting in seeing how other clones will be able to get their chips removed!

Answer (score 1):

In *The Bad Batch* episode "Battle Scars," the Batch must break into an abandoned *Venator*-class Star Destroyer in order to utilize its medical facilities to remove their chips. This is noted to be risky but the only available option. It is beyond reach of the medical equipment possessed by Tech.

[image]

This process also requires the technical/medical abilities of Tech, as well as his specially made brain scanner.

This event, combined with the fact that there is no evidence Wolfe or Gregor had a Jedi help them, leads me to the conclusion that the Force is not required. However, advanced technology and some degree of medical skill is.